# Header-only vector implementation in C

Tags: c, memory-management, vectors, memory-optimization

I tried to make a generic, header-only vector thingy I can use in other projects in the future. I omitted documentation comments because it's already quite long.

```
#ifndef __VECTOR__
#define __VECTOR__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static int VECTOR_DEFAULT_SIZE = 1;

typedef struct vector {
  void** data;
  int max;
  int size;
} vector;

static int vector_size(vector* v) {
  return v->size;
}

static int vector_capacity(vector* v) {
  return v->max;
}

static void* vector_get(vector* v, int i) {
  if (i < 0 || i >= vector_capacity(v))
    return NULL;
  return v->data[i];
}

static void vector_set(vector* v, int i, void* e) {
  if (i < 0 || i >= vector_capacity(v))
    return;

  v->data[i] = e;
}

static vector* vector_create_sized(int size) {
  vector* v = malloc(sizeof(vector));
  v->data = malloc(sizeof(void*) * size);
  v->max = size;
  v->size = 0;

  return v;
};

static vector* vector_create() {
  return vector_create_sized(VECTOR_DEFAULT_SIZE);
};

static void vector_clear(vector* v) {
  for(int i = 0; i < v->max; i++) {
    vector_set(v, i, NULL);
  }
  v->size = 0;
}

static bool vector_is_empty(vector* v) {
  return vector_size(v) == 0;
}

static void vector_resize(vector* v, int size) {
  if (size > vector_capacity(v)) {
    void** new = malloc(sizeof(void*) * size);

    for(int i = 0; i < vector_capacity(v); i++) {
      new[i] = vector_get(v, i);
    }

    free(v->data);
    v->data = new;
    v->max = size;
  }
}

static void vector_insert(vector* v, int i, void* e) {
  if (i < 0 || i >= vector_capacity(v))
    return;

  for(int j = vector_capacity(v) - 2; j >= i; j--) {
    vector_set(v, j + 1, vector_get(v, j));
  }

  vector_set(v, i, e);

  v->size++;

  if (vector_size(v) == vector_capacity(v))
    vector_resize(v, vector_capacity(v) * 2);
}

static void vector_unshift(vector* v, void* e) {
  vector_insert(v, 0, e);
}

static void vector_push(vector* v, void* e) {
  vector_insert(v, vector_size(v), e);
}

static void vector_foreach(vector* v, void (*func)(int, const void*)) {
  if (vector_is_empty(v))
    return;

  for(int i = 0; i < vector_size(v); i++) {
    func(i, v->data[i]);
  }
}

static vector* vector_map(vector* v, void* (*func)(int, const void*)) {
  vector* w = vector_create_sized(vector_capacity(v));

  for(int i = 0; i < vector_size(v); i++) {
    void* e = vector_get(v, i);
    vector_push(w, func(i, e));
  }

  return w;
}

static vector* vector_filter(vector* v, bool (*func)(int, const void*)) {
  vector* w = vector_create_sized(VECTOR_DEFAULT_SIZE);

  for(int i = 0; i < vector_size(v); i++) {
    void* e = vector_get(v, i);
    if (func(i, e))
      vector_push(w, e);
  }

  return w;
}

static bool vector_any(vector* v, bool (*func)(int, const void*)) {
  for(int i = 0; i < vector_size(v); i++) {
    void* e = vector_get(v, i);
    if (func(i, e))
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}

static bool vector_all(vector* v, bool (*func)(int, const void*)) {
  for(int i = 0; i < vector_size(v); i++) {
    void* e = vector_get(v, i);
    if (!func(i, e))
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}

static vector* vector_copy(vector* v) {
  vector* w = vector_create_sized(vector_capacity(v));

  for(int i = 0; i < vector_size(v); i++) {
    void* e = vector_get(v, i);
    vector_push(w, e);
  }

  return w;
}

static void* vector_remove(vector* v, int i) {
  if (i < 0 || i >= vector_capacity(v) || vector_is_empty(v))
    return NULL;

  void* tmp = vector_get(v, i);

  for(int j = i; j < vector_size(v); j++) {
    vector_set(v, j, vector_get(v, j + 1));
  }

  v->size--;

  return tmp;
}

static void vector_erase(vector* v, bool (*func)(int, const void*)) {
  for(int i = vector_size(v) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    void* e = vector_get(v, i);
    if (func(i, e))
      vector_remove(v, i);
  }
}

static void* vector_pop(vector* v) {
  return vector_remove(v, vector_size(v) - 1);
}

static void* vector_shift(vector* v) {
  return vector_remove(v, 0);
}

static void vector_swap(vector* v, int i, int j) {
  if (i < 0 || i >= vector_size(v) || j < 0 || j >= vector_size(v))
    return;

  void* tmp = vector_get(v, i);
  vector_set(v, i, vector_get(v, j));
  vector_set(v, j, tmp);
}

static void vector_sort(vector* v, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*)) {
  for (int i = 0; i < vector_size(v); i++) {
    int j = i;
    while (j > 0 && cmp(vector_get(v, j - 1), vector_get(v, j)) > 0) {
      vector_swap(v, j, j - 1);
      j--;
    }
  }
}

static void vector_reverse(vector* v) {
  int i = vector_size(v) - 1;
  int j = 0;

  while(i > j) {
    vector_swap(v, i, j);
    i--;
    j++;
  }
}

static vector* vector_concat(vector* a, vector* b) {
  vector* c = vector_create_sized(vector_size(a) + vector_size(b));

  for(int i = 0; i < vector_size(a); i++) {
    vector_push(c, vector_get(a, i));
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < vector_size(b); i++) {
    vector_push(c, vector_get(b, i));
  }

  return c;
}

static void vector_debug(vector* v) {
  printf("\n----------\nVector %i/%i\n", vector_size(v), vector_capacity(v));
  for(int i = 0; i < vector_size(v); i++) {
    printf("%i %p\n", i, vector_get(v, i));
  }

  for(int i = vector_size(v); i < vector_capacity(v); i++) {
    printf("%i NULL\n", i);
  }
  printf("----------\n");
}

static void vector_free(vector* v) {
  free(v->data);
  free(v);
};

#endif
```

Also here's a short example of usage, generating 2 vectors of random ints, concatenating, sorting and then reversing them in a third list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "vector.h"

void free_int(int x, const void* p) {
  int* i = (int*)p;
  free(i);
}

void print_int(int x, const void* p) {
  int* i = (int*)p;
  int j = *i;
  printf("%i ", j);
}

int sort(const void* a, const void* b) {
  return *((int*)a) - *((int*)b);
}

int main(void) {
  srand(time(NULL));

  vector* a = vector_create();
  vector* b = vector_create();

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int* n = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *n = rand() % 50;
    vector_push(a, n);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int* n = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *n = rand() % 50;
    vector_push(b, n);
  }

  printf("A: ");
  vector_foreach(a, print_int);
  printf("\nB: ");
  vector_foreach(b, print_int);

  vector* c = vector_concat(a, b);
  vector_sort(c, sort);
  vector_reverse(c);

  printf("\n\nA concat B sorted descending:\n");
  vector_foreach(c, print_int);

  vector_foreach(c, free_int);
  vector_free(a);
  vector_free(b);
  vector_free(c);

  return 0;
};
```

Comment: Comment on `vector_resize`: it's probably easier and faster to use `realloc`.

Answer (score 3):

**Why one way re-sizing?**

`vector_resize()` only allows the vector to grow.

**`vector_insert()` growth oddity**

Code can grow the vector size indefinitely if done by inserting at the end, yet quietly fails if the insert is far beyond the end.

I'd expect the function to not grow at all or allow an insertion anywhere.

**Sort can overflow**

In `sort()`, rather than `return a - b` (with its UB overflow), use the idiomatic, not overflow possible: `return (a > b) - (a < b)`.

**Avoid C++ keywords**

For potential portability as well as clarity, avoid `new` as an object in C code.

Code *looks* wrong.

```
void** new = malloc(sizeof(void*) * size);
```

**Allocate to the size of the de-referenced object**

Avoid size errors.  Do not allocate to the size of the type.  The below is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// void** new = malloc(sizeof(void*) * size);
void** nu = malloc(sizeof *nu * size);
```

**Allow state**

With `vector_any()` pass in a *state* argument and return `int` for additional flexibility.

```
static int vector_any_alt(vector* v, void *state, int (*func)(state, int, const void*))  {
  for(int i = 0; i < vector_size(v); i++) {
    int retval = func(state, i, v->data[i]);
    if (retval) {
      return retval;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Minor: `int` indexing vs. `size_t`**

I would have used `size_t` indexing rather than `int`, yet I suspect OP's desires `int`.

**Naming**

Why call use `.max` instead of `.capacity`? or
Why call use `vector_capacity()` instead of `vector_max()`.

**Use `const`**

Various functions like `vector_is_empty(vector* v)` convey meaning better, allow for expanded use and sometime optimize better with `const`.

```
// vector_is_empty(vector* v)
vector_is_empty(const vector* v)
```

**Use `(void)`**

With `()`, no parameters checking occurs allowing `vector_create(1,2,3)` to not generate an error.

```
// static vector* vector_create()
static vector* vector_create(void)
```

**Why clear to capacity?**

`vector_clear()` clears all `v->max` rather than `v>size`.

**Why upper case object name?**

`static int VECTOR_DEFAULT_SIZE = 1;` will certainly throw off users.  Consider `static int vector_default_size = 1;`